# Add shapefile with JS sample code

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I want to add a shapefile to the map from the folder. I have used JS sample code but it does not work for me. It gives an error in response, featurecollection. It does not go into the request block so I changed it to esri request but still code not working.

```
var portalUrl = "https://www.arcgis.com";

  esriConfig.defaults.io.proxyUrl = "/proxy/";
  on(dojo.byId("uploadForm"), "change", function (event) {
    var fileName = event.target.value.toLowerCase();

  <!-- if (sniff("ie")) { //filename is full path in IE so extract the file name -->
      <!-- var arr = fileName.split("\\"); -->
      <!-- fileName = arr[arr.length - 1]; -->
    <!-- } -->
    if (fileName.indexOf(".zip") !== -1) {//is file a zip - if not notify user
      generateFeatureCollection(fileName);
    }
    else {
      alert("Add shapefile as .zip file");
    }
  });


  function generateFeatureCollection (fileName) {
    var name = fileName.split(".");
    name = name[0].replace("c:\\fakepath\\", "");

    var params = {
      'name': name,
      'targetSR': map.spatialReference,
      'maxRecordCount': 1000,
      'enforceInputFileSizeLimit': true,
      'enforceOutputJsonSizeLimit': true
    };

    //var extent = scaleUtils.getExtentForScale(map, 40000);
    var extent = esri.geometry.getExtentForScale(map, 40000);
    var resolution = extent.getWidth() / map.width;
    params.generalize = true;
    params.maxAllowableOffset = resolution;
    params.reducePrecision = true;
    params.numberOfDigitsAfterDecimal = 0;

               var myContent = {
      'filetype': 'shapefile',
      'publishParameters': JSON.stringify(params),
      'f': 'json',
      //'callback.html': 'textarea'
    };

    esriRequest({
      url: portalUrl + '/sharing/rest/content/features/generate',
      content: myContent,
       form: dojo.byId('uploadForm'),
      handleAs: 'json',
      load: lang.hitch(this, function (response) {
        <!-- if (response.error) { -->
          <!-- errorHandler(response.error); -->
          <!-- return; -->
        <!-- } -->

        var layerName = response.FeatureCollection.layers[0].layerDefinition.name;

        addShapefileToMap(response.FeatureCollection);
      }),
     //error: lang.hitch(this, errorHandler)
    });
  }

  function addShapefileToMap (featureCollection) {

    var fullExtent;
    var layers = [];

    arrayUtils.forEach(featureCollection.layers, function (layer) {
      var infoTemplate = new InfoTemplate("Details", "${*}");
      var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer(layer, {
        infoTemplate: infoTemplate
      });

      featureLayer.on('click', function (event) {
        map.infoWindow.setFeatures([event.graphic]);
      });
      changeRenderer(featureLayer);
      fullExtent = fullExtent ?
        fullExtent.union(featureLayer.fullExtent) : featureLayer.fullExtent;
      layers.push(featureLayer);
    });
    map.addLayers(layers);
    map.setExtent(fullExtent.expand(1.25), true);

  }

  function changeRenderer (layer) {
    //change the default symbol for the feature collection for polygons and points
    var symbol = null;
    switch (layer.geometryType) {
      case 'esriGeometryPoint':
        symbol = new PictureMarkerSymbol({
          'angle': 0,
          'xoffset': 0,
          'yoffset': 0,
          'type': 'esriPMS',
          'url': 'https://static.arcgis.com/images/Symbols/Shapes/BluePin1LargeB.png',
          'contentType': 'image/png',
          'width': 20,
          'height': 20
        });
        break;
      case 'esriGeometryPolygon':
        symbol = new SimpleFillSymbol(SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
          new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
            new Color([112, 112, 112]), 1), new Color([136, 136, 136, 0.25]));
        break;
    }
    if (symbol) {
      layer.setRenderer(new SimpleRenderer(symbol));
    }
```

}

on one shapefile it gives me error 
Tried to register widget with id==dijit_layout_AccordionContainer_0 but that id is already registered

on other shapefile it gives error time out exceeds.
 i am using the same sample code i do not understands why it gives error

Comment: Please  [Edit] your question to contain the **exact** error message, and indicate in the source where that is.

Comment: If you use the code as is from the original sample, does that work for you? https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/portal_addshapefile.html

Comment: Does it work with a very basic shapefile?  There are some limitations abuot number of features, file size, geometry types, compression format etc.  See http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/shapefiles.htm

Comment: i have used the same sample code . but it does not work for me. it does not work for any shapefile @vince i got error on every line now i have error for arrayutils